# Show that $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^n(kx) \, dx=\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^n(x) \, dx$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Show that $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^n(kx) \, dx=\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^n(x) \, dx$, with $k\in \mathbb N^*$

I would really appreciate some help with this exercise because I really don't know how to begin. What I have been able to pick on so far is that $\cos(x)=\cos(kx)=1$  for $x=0$ and $x=2\pi$, and if we raise $1$ to any power it is still $1$. I don't know how I can use this to prove the equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing special about $\cos^n$.
All that is needed is
that it is periodic.

If $f(x)$ 
is a periodic function
of period $T$ then

\begin{align}
\int_0^T f(kx)\,dx
&=\frac1{k}\int_0^{kT} f(y) \, dy
\qquad y = kx, dx = dy/k\\
&=\frac1{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\int_{jT}^{(j+1)T} f(y) \,dy
\qquad\text{split into } k \text{ parts}\\
&=\frac1{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\int_{0}^{T} f(y+jT) \,dy
\qquad\text{shift origin to zero}\\
&=\frac1{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\int_0^T f(y) \,dy
\qquad\text{use the fact that it is periodic}\\
&=\frac1{k} \left (k\int_0^T f(y) \, dy\right)
\qquad k\text{ copies of the same thing}\\
&=\int_0^T f(y) \, dy
\qquad\text{Done!}\\
\end{align}

Comment: The use of "array" rather than "align" was why your integral signs looked like $\int$ rather than like $\displaystyle\int.$ I changed that, and also but a small space before $dy,$ thus: $$f(y)\,dy \text{ rather than } f(y) dy.$$ Also I used \left( and \right) in the line that says $\text{“} k \text{ copies''},$ so the parentheses are bigger.

Comment: This is still a lot for me to take in, but I love that you explained what you've done after every step.

Answer (score 1):

By letting $t=kx$, then $dt=k\,dx$ and
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}{\cos^n(kx)}\,dx
&=\int_0^{2\pi k}{\cos^n(t)}\,\frac{dt}{k}
=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k\int_0^{2\pi}{\cos^n(t+2\pi(j-1))}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k\int_0^{2\pi}{\cos^n(t)}\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}{\cos^n(t)}\,dt
\end{align}$$
where we used the fact that the cosine has period $T=2\pi$ and therefore $$\cos(t+2\pi(j-1))=\cos(t).$$
Along the same lines, you may generalize the property: if $f$ is any integrable function with period $T$ then
$$\int_0^T f(kx)\,dx=\int_0^{T} f(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: I definitely can't. This is way over my head. I should've mentioned I am looking for a high school friendly approach.

Comment: @RaduGabriel Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Using the substitution $u = kx$:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^n kx \; dx = \int_0^{2k\pi} \frac{1}{k} \cos^n u \; du  $$

Since $\cos^n u$ has period $2\pi$, this last integral is equal to

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{k} \cos^n u \; du  +\int_{2\pi}^{4\pi} \frac{1}{k} \cos^n u \; du  +\cdots \int_{2(k-1)}^{2k\pi} \frac{1}{k} \cos^n u \; du,$$

and each of these integrals is equal to the first one (each one is over one complete period.)  And there are $k$ of them, so you have the above

$$= k\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{k} \cos^n u \; du = \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^n x \; dx$$

which is your other integral once you change $u$ to $x$.

Comment: Ok, this is what I really was looking for, seems like the easiest approach, thank you!